# Blazor WASM Unhandled exception rendering component: Object of type <my component> does not have a property matching the name myEventCallback

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Ok kids, this is straight outta chatGPT.  Just getting my feet wet with Blazor, so I asked chatGPT to give me a simple hello world application, that would display a login form when a button was clicked and change the message if the right email was passed.  Simple stuff.  The result failed with the message in the title.

I don't know much, but I do know, it isn't a type-o. Intellisense and chatGPT confirmed the code "looks" right.  What gives?

ALogin.razor

```
@using blazor1.Pages


<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" @bind="email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" @bind="password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" @onclick="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<LoginModel> LogMeIn { get; set; } 
 
    private string email = "";
    private string password = "";

    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }


    private async void Submit()
    {
        var lm = new LoginModel
        {
            Email = email,
            Password = password
        };

        await LogMeIn.InvokeAsync(lm);
    }


}
```

HelloWord.razor

```
@using blazor1.Pages


<h1>@message</h1>
<button @onclick="ToggleLoginForm">ClickMe</button>

@if (showLoginForm)
{
    <ALogin @LogMeIn="rLogin" />
}

@code {
    private string message = "Hey ";
    private bool showLoginForm = false;

    private void ToggleLoginForm()
    {
        showLoginForm = !showLoginForm;
    }

    private void rLogin(string email, string password)
    {
        if (email == "something@gmail.com")
        {
            message = "Hello John";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a client connecting to  a server.  The class object LoginModel gets serialized in the client and put into the body of the request.  Then server deserializes the body of the request.  The server is not recognizing the body of the request as a LoginModel.  Where are you defining the LoginModel in the client?  I do not see client code.

Comment: when you just want to have a sample for starting learning, you could create a new project within VS and use the template, just note to choose the authentication type so that you would have a login module. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC5fj.png

Comment: thanks for your reply, I missed the @using claim on the top of the code. Could you pls click the √ beside my post to accept it as the answer and end this question?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue when using your code,

[image]

and after some fix, it worked now.

[image]

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" @bind="email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" @bind="password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" @onclick="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<LoginModel> LogMeIn { get; set; }

    private string email = "";
    private string password = "";

    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }


    private async void Submit()
    {
        var lm = new LoginModel
            {
                Email = email,
                Password = password
            };

        await LogMeIn.InvokeAsync(lm);
    }
}
```

and the index.razor component(parent component)

```
<h1>@message</h1>
<button @onclick="ToggleLoginForm">ClickMe</button>

@if (showLoginForm)
{
    <ALogin LogMeIn="@rLogin" />
}

@code {
    private string message = "Hey ";
    private bool showLoginForm = false;

    private void ToggleLoginForm()
    {
        showLoginForm = !showLoginForm;
    }

    private void rLogin(LoginModel mod)
    {
        if (mod.Email == "something@gmail.com")
        {
            message = "Hello John";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#eventcallback) which provide us a guidance about using event handling.

Comment: Thank you for this. I copied, I pasted, I failed.  The Index.razor file isn't happy.  

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'LoginModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Got it working after I added: @using static ALogin  

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know much, but I do know, it isn't a type-o. Intellisense and chatGPT confirmed the code "looks" right. What gives?

Trusting ChatGPT to generate your code!

Here's a very different version.  Take it or leave it, it's written by an intelligent life form rather than a parrot with a big dictionary.

A value object to represent your base data.

```cs
public record LoginData(string Email, string Password);
```

A very different version of your `AlogIn`.

```cs
@if (Show)
{
    <EditForm Model="model">
        <div class="m-2 p-2">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" @bind="model.Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" @bind="model.Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-2 text-end">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" @onclick="Submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
}

@code {
    private LoginModel model = default!;

    [Parameter] public LoginData Value { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<LoginData> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public bool Show { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> ShowChanged { get; set; }

    // Override to run a null check on Value
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Value);

        if (model is null || Value != model.AsRecord())
            model = new(this.Value);

        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    // The Edit Model
    public class LoginModel
    {
        // can apply validation here
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public LoginModel(LoginData data)
            => this.Load(data);

        public void Load(LoginData data)
        {
            this.Email = data.Email;
            this.Password = data.Password;
        }

        public LoginData AsRecord()
            => new(this.Email, this.Password);
    }

    private async void Submit()
    {
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(model.AsRecord());
        await ShowChanged.InvokeAsync(false);
    }
}
```

And the main page.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ToggleLoginForm">Edit User Data</button>

<ALogIn @bind-Value="_loginData" @bind-Show="_showLoginForm" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>User EMail: @_loginData.Email</pre>
    <pre>Password @_loginData.Password</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private LoginData _loginData = new("me@you.com", "p455w0rd");
    private bool _showLoginForm = false;

    private void ToggleLoginForm()
    {
        _showLoginForm = !_showLoginForm;
    }
}
```